# Trying to fit one loop's results into a datagrid populated by another loop

Tags: c#, list, datagridview

Earlier today (with help from here) we created the following code.

```
var sLines = File.ReadAllLines("//dnc/WaterJet/MTI-WJ/" + cboPartProgram.Text)
                 .Where(s => !s.StartsWith("'") && s.Contains("S"))
                 .Select(s => new
                     {
                         SValue = Regex.Match(s, "(?<=S)[\\d.]*").Value
                     })
                 .ToArray();

foreach (var lines in sLines)
{
    double sTime = double.Parse(lines.SValue);
}
```

Further down in the app the datagridview is being populated from a list, a list created by a sql statement's results.

```
foreach (WjDwellOffsets offset in dwellTimes)
{
    origionalDwellOffsets.Add(offset.dwellOffset);

    dgvDwellTimes.Rows.Add(new object[] { offset.positionId, sTime, offset.dwellOffset, 0, offset.dwellOffset, "Update", (offset.dateTime > new DateTime(1900, 1, 1)) ? offset.dateTime.ToString() : "" });
    DataGridViewDisableButtonCell btnCell = ((DataGridViewDisableButtonCell)dgvDwellTimes.Rows[dgvDwellTimes.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[5]);
    btnCell.Enabled = false;
}
```

As you can see, I just put `sTime` in there to show where I need it.  But clearly this wont work, 1 because it's out of context and any way I've tried to incorporate this it doubles everything or worse because I'm looping through the file, but then I'm looping through what's added to the datagrid etc.  How can I incorporate `sTime` results (which is 80 lines)  with the 80 lines of the list that's being populated in datagridview?  I'm not sure how to merge the results from `sTime` into the grid without messing it up.

Comment: Does anyone else know what might work? Satish helped but unfortunately those things I had tried and they produced the same problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you're looking for this:

Since both loops have the same counter limit (80 in your case), and they don't seem to require a separation, you can simply merge them in a single normal `for` loop.

```
double stime;

for (int i = 0; i < sLines.Count(); i++)
{
    sTime = double.Parse(sLines[i].SValue); // Or sLines.ElementAt(i)

    origionalDwellOffsets.Add(dwellTimes[i].dwellOffset); // Or dwellOffset.ElementAt(i)

    dgvDwellTimes.Rows.Add(new object[] { dwellTimes[i].positionId, sTime, dwellTimes[i].dwellOffset, 0, dwellTimes[i].dwellOffset, "Update", (dwellTimes[i].dateTime > new     DateTime(1900, 1, 1)) ? dwellTimes[i].dateTime.ToString() : "" });
    DataGridViewDisableButtonCell btnCell = ((DataGridViewDisableButtonCell)dgvDwellTimes.Rows[dgvDwellTimes.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[5]);     
}
```

Comment: can you please check my update above.  Thanks a ton!

Comment: @Lee sorry but you cannot expect people to do all your code. I understand that you have a hard time but if my answer solved the problem you were initially asking, please mark it as such and ask a new question in a new post. I suggest you remove the edits you made and use that in the new question, if you need it.

Comment: I took what you gave me, added it to what I had.  I showed what I did, showed what I edited and explained what was occurring.  Telling me what I did wrong isn't doing my work.  My only concern with starting a new question was getting people wanting to help but not knowing where any of this came from since all the work and explanations were done here.  Just seems unnecessary but I'll do that.

Comment: And now I've reached my question limit.  Oh well.

Comment: @Lee It's not unnecessary; your question went from getting data from 1 loop to another _to_ dealing with null/empty values in your grid. The purpose of questions is to solve a concise problem or to at least guide OP towards an answer. Your post is now 2 separate problems and therefore should be split in 2 questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
double sTime ;              

var sLines = File.ReadAllLines("//dnc/WaterJet/MTI-WJ/" +   cboPartProgram.Text)
                 .Where(s => !s.StartsWith("'") && s.Contains("S"))
                 .Select(s => new
                     {
                         SValue = Regex.Match(s, "(?<=S)[\\d.]*").Value
                     })
                 .ToArray();

foreach (var lines in sLines)
{
    sTime = double.Parse(lines.SValue);
}

foreach (WjDwellOffsets offset in dwellTimes)
{
    origionalDwellOffsets.Add(offset.dwellOffset);

    dgvDwellTimes.Rows.Add(new object[] { offset.positionId, sTime, offset.dwellOffset, 0, offset.dwellOffset, "Update", (offset.dateTime > new DateTime(1900, 1, 1)) ? offset.dateTime.ToString() : "" });
    DataGridViewDisableButtonCell btnCell = ((DataGridViewDisableButtonCell)dgvDwellTimes.Rows[dgvDwellTimes.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[5]);            
}

btnCell.Enabled = false;
```

Comment: That was the first thing I tried but that doesn't work.  What it does do is it add's all 80 lines from offset for the first line of sTime.  Then it adds all 80 lines of offset again for the 2nd line of sTime.  So rather than 80 lines total in datagridview you end up with 6,400 line. 80x80.

Comment: I tried this one too :-) What this one does is, it doesn't apply each line from  sTime.  It just takes the very last entry from sTime loop and applies it to all 80 entries in the datagridview.

Comment: @SatishPatil You should provide at least a little explanation of your solution.

Comment: @Mat do you have any suggestion's yourself?

Comment: @Lee make `stime` a `double[]`. Fill it with the first loop, and iterate through it in the second one. Only thing I'm not quite sure is what's the relation between an `offset` and a `stime` in your app; is it 1 to 1 ?

Comment: @Mat offset is pulling the data (in this case 80 lines of info) from a table on the oracle server.  The sTime I need to get straight from the source, so matching 80 lines.  I just had to add those sTimes to the datagridview table that is being populated w/ that oracle data.  Which works, I just can't get it to display correctly in the dgv.

Comment: @Mat still having a tough time, I don't think I'm doing it right.  I'm still very much a novice.  Anything you can edit above that you think would help would be great, visuals help me a lot figuring out what someone did and why.